# Should I use a linear transformation for my logistic regression model?

Tags: regression, logistic

I am testing to see whether the only continuous variable in my logistic regression model upholds the linearity assumption. In your opinion, does my model require a transformation based on this partial residual plot? I am unsure because there appears to be a slight linear trend, but for the most part it seems like there is no clear pattern at al.

Thanks[image]